# Extract value at the point at which the odds ratio of an event is greater than 1 from GLM in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I have run a logistic regression in R and have obtained the odds ratio of an event for a one point increase in my exposure. I would like to find the value of my exposure at the point at which the odds ratio for the event is greater than 1.

My outcome is a binary variable event yes or no.
My exposure is a continuous numeric variable ranging from 1.30 to 29.25.

The logistic regression equation is something like:
glm(event ~ exposure + covariate1 + covariate 2 , family = binomial (link='logit'), data = data)

Is there a method to extract the value of the exposure related to an odd ratio for the event greater than 1?

I want to do something similar to this paper https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2000803 in which they calculated the Troponin level post surgery associated with a hazard ratio of death of greater than 1.

I have been stumped on how to approach this so haven't tried anything in R yet.

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure how much this is a programming question vs. a statistical question. There may be a library in R that can get you this automatically, but here's how I would go about it.

First, instead of dealing with odds ratios, which my brain doesn't like, I'm going to talk about log-odds, which is useful because it's the scale on which a logistic regression gets reported by default in R. An odds ratio of 1 is equal to zero in log odds. First, here I simulate some data:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rbinom(100, 1, plogis(x))

df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

Now I'm going to fit a model and get the coefficients:

```
model_fit <- glm(y ~ x,
                 data = df,
                 family = binomial())

summary(model_fit)$coefficients
             Estimate Std. Error  z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 0.3995191  0.2265253 1.763684 0.0777852049
x           1.1669519  0.3042227 3.835848 0.0001251318
```

Let's remind ourselves of the simple version of our model, which is predicting the log odds of an outcome based on a combination of an Intercept and one predictor. You want to know the values of the predictor `x` where the log odds are zero, so we have the following equation:

[image]

We can slot in our coefficients and then it is a simple matter of having to solve for x

[image]

When we subtract the Intercept from both sides, then divide both sides by the estimate, we have x isolated:

[image]

Running this through a calculator (or R) gives us `-0.3423612`. We can check this by plotting the effect of x on y and seeing if that is the value of x where y = 0.5 on the probability scale:

```
p <- plot_model(model_fit,
                type = "pred")

p$x + geom_vline(xintercept = -0.342)
```

[image]

It will be more complicated to do this with covariates, as it will depend on the values of the covariates.